# Enviar mail a varios destinatarios con Mail

Tags: laravel, mail

una consulta, estoy enviando un mail a varios destinatarios pero no me funciona, enviando a un solo destinatario no tengo problema, en mi controlador tengo el siguiente código

```
$email = Correos::where('seccion', '=', 'GERENCIA')->first();
$mail->envioMail($email, $personal);
```

Lo cual me trae lo siguiente (linea color amarilla):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi función envioMail funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
public function envioMail ($email, $personal){
        $datas = [
            "nombre" => $personal->nombre_personal,
        ];

         Mail::send(["html" => 'Usuario.envio_mail'], $datas, function ($message) use ($email) {
            $message->to($email)
                ->subject('Saludos')
                ->from('info@ua.cl', 'UA');
        });

    }
```

Pero sucede que `$email` no me deja enviar a los 3 destinatarios que necesito enviar y se cae, como puedo hacer que esto me funcione a todos los email que necesito enviar. Ayuda plis

Answer (score 1):

la variable email es un string con varios correos "pedro@gmail.com,carlos@ua.cl,sergio@ua.cl", Te recomiendo que hagas un explode de la variable $email y de ahi se lo entregues como argumento a $message->to.

```
$emails = explode(',', $email->mail);
$message->to(...$emails)
                ->subject('Saludos')
                ->from('info@ua.cl', 'UA');
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero perdona mi ignoracia cuando tu me hablas de esto $message->to(...$emails), los ... que significan ya que si imprimo la variable $emails me arroja esto array:5 [▼
  0 => "{"id":1"
  1 => ""entidad":"GERENCIA""
  2 => ""mail":"pedro@gmail.com"
  3 => "carlos@ua.cl"
  4 => "sergio@ua.cl"}"
]

Comment: Muchas gracias @Philippe Thiers, ahora entendí lo que debía hacer

Comment: es el splat operator, permite desempaquetar un array y transformarlo en una lista de argumentos para las funciones. https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

Comment: igual edite la respuesta arriba, puse mal el parametro al explode

Comment: Si me di cuenta, porque asi no me funcionó, incuyendo el campo me funcionó, muchas gracias!